# Android cannot resolve symbol imported

Tags: java, android

I am following a guideline of a book called *Head First Android Development
A Brain-Friendly Guide By Dawn Griffiths, David Griffiths*.
The problem is that i completely copy the code suggested by the book but it doesn't work.
I have already tried to copy the code in the book website https://github.com/dogriffiths/HeadFirstAndroid/tree/master/chapter06/Starbuzz
but it still not work

It is the code form DrinkActivity.java:

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DrinkActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNO = "drinkNo";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);
    }

    int drinkNo= (Integer)getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);
    Drink drink = Drink.drinks[drinkNo];

    ImageView photo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo);
    photo.setImageResource(drink.getImageResourceID());
    photo.setContentDescription(drink.getName());

    TextView name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(drink.getName());

    TextView description=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.description);
    description.setText(drink.getDescription());
}
```

> the method between cannot resolve symbol the method

such method are in another class as below:

```
package com.hfad.starbuzz;

public class Drink {
private String name;
private String description;
private int imageResourceId;

public static final Drink[] drinks = {
        new Drink("Latte", "A couple of espresso shots with steamed milk" , R.drawable.latte),
        new Drink("Cappuccino", "Espresso, hot milk, and a steamed milk foam", R.drawable.cappuccino),
        new Drink("Filter", "Highest quality beans roasted and brewed fresh", R.drawable.filter)
};

private Drink(String name, String description, int imageResourceId) {
    this.name= name;
    this.description= description;
    this.imageResourceId= imageResourceId;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return  description;
}

public String getName() {
    return  name;
}

public  int getImageResourceID() {
    return imageResourceId;
}

public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
}
```

and the method `setContentDescription` and `setText` should be in `TextView` and `ImageView` in my understanding.

The problem is that i had already import `TextView` and `ImageView`.

So what happened?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is outside of a method, paste it into the `onCreate(`) method between the `{`  and `}`

Comment: Thank you so much, it is a obvious error but a starter like me cannot find it, I will remember it. Thank you.